# How can I replicate this image of a tied-up balloon?

Tags: objects, edit-mode, transforms, sculpting, sculpt-mode

I want to make a picture of the balloon tied with a string like in the picture.

Is there any useful function for that?

Should I reduce the scale of the dots that the string passes by and sculpture them?

[image: image of roped balloon and current blender approach]

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 8):

You could do it with a cloth simulation: Create a cube, subdivide it (put the *Smoothness* value at 1 in the *Operator Box*), cut several edge loops with the knife (<kbd>K</kbd> to activate, <kbd>C</kbd> to cut through), assign them to a vertex group (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>):

[image]

Give your object a *Cloth* simulation, choose the group as *Pin Group*, enable the *Pressure* option, choose the pressure strength:

[image]

After a bit of sculpting (*Cloth Filter* brush in *Pinch* mode, with the *Cavity* option enabled):

[image]